# Parsing nexted XML tags with XMLParser

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, xmlpullparser

My nextTag() seems to error out on tag 4 right now. I'm not to sure why it's throwing an exception?

So here's the structure of the XML

```
<OuterTag>
     <Tag1 />
     <Tag2>Some data</Tag2>
     <Tag3>Some data</Tag3>
     <Tag4>Some data</Tag4>
</OuterTag>
```

Here's what I'm doing currently to parse:

```
if (tag.equals("OuterTag")) {
        int eventType = reader.nextTag();
        if (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
            String subTag = reader.getName();
            while (!subTag.equals("OuterTag")) {
                subTag = reader.getName();

                if (subTag.equals("Tag2")) {
                    //do some data manipulation
                }
                else if (subTag.equals("Tag3")) {
                    //do some data manipulation
                }
                eventType = reader.nextTag();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

It seems that after Tag4, the XML throws an exception on eventType=reader.nextTag();

Comment: "It seems that after Tag4, the XML throws an exception on eventType=reader.nextTag();" => can you add stacktrace? Or, read it and post the line which causes the exception

Comment: It's reader.nextTag() that causes the exception.

Comment: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unexpected type (position:TEXT 1@21:7601 in java.io.InputStreamReader@424862e0)

Comment: Oh, strange i didn't notice before. Anyway your XML is wrong. when you need to close a tag you should use `</TAG_NAME>`, so `<Tag2>Some data<Tag2>` will be `<Tag2>Some data</Tag2>`. Same for others.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was writing a generic XML, but they do have the appropriate end tags, I'll update.